# Get List<string> with regex from docx content

Tags: c#, regex, office-interop

I have a doc which I load with interop. I need to find match content with a regex.
Some words in the doc are between $$ : `$$theWord$$`
So I need to get all of them for displaying to user and know what he wants to set for replace.

```
object fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(templatePath, pj.Nom);
object missing = Type.Missing;
Application word = new Application();
Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
doc.Activate();
string content = ((dynamic)doc).Content.Text;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\$\$.*\$\$$", RegexOptions.Multiline);

List<string> tags = regex.Matches(content).Cast<string>().ToList();
```

The problem is my regex get only one word who begin on the first `&&` found and finish on the last...

Please help me, I hate regex :(

Comment: Use `@"\$\$.*?\$\$"` (or if you really need to match them at the end of lines, keep the last `$` in the pattern).

Comment: Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew, I love you !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you explain why the `?` exactly makes it work?

Comment: @MongZhu It takes all characters but no break line

Comment: `.*?` is a lazy version of `.*`, see [their difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great Link, helped me a lot. Thank you